# POWERPOINT VBA Select a group of shapes and change color

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to select several shapes in a slide and change their colour. I have tried :

```vb
    Sub psu_off()
    
    Dim shp As Object
    Dim myArray() As Variant
    Dim myRange As Object
    myArray = Array("C1", "R1", "R2")
      
    Set myRange = ActivePresentation.Slides(22).Shapes.Range(myArray)
    
    For Each shp In myRange
        
        shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 155, 244)
    Next

End Sub
```

The code above only change colour to the first elemnt "C1". Looks like is not looping. What is the issue?

Comment: I created a slide with three shapes, renamed then to the names in your code and the macro ran fine, recoloring all three shapes.

Comment: Why it doesn't work in my laptop?..I will restart it

Comment: Found the issue...(thanks John for your time).  The other two shapes are part of a "group" (shape and text). ..Now How can I access a element of a group??

Comment: You'll need to add the name of the shape within the group. You needn't mention the group name. Also, you can have text within the shape instead of having two separate elements.